# Is there a difference between normal code signing and "authenticode"?

Tags: windows, code-signing

I need to build a dll that will be loaded from ms sql server.

I have a codesigning certificate issued by sectigo.

I signed the dll using `signtool /a /fd SHA256 <dll name>`. I verified the signatures with `signtool verify /pa <dll name>` which passed successfuly. (`signtool verify /a` does not pass, however)

I didn't add a timestamp as I keep getting `SignTool Error: The specified algorithm cannot be used or is invalid` (Is this related? Is a timestamp needed?)

However, when trying to load the dll into sql server, I keep getting an error that states that either the path is bad (which it isn't) or "invalid Authenticode signature".

(To clarify, my dev machine is where the sql server is running as well, and sectigo is a trust root CA)

I really can't be able to figure out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I will, after I get this thing to work. Right now I'm more concerned with testing the code with a new build each time.

Comment: SQLServer can manage its own certificates according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-signing-stored-procedures-with-a-certificate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15 Maybe you have to sign the DLL with an internal certificate instead of a certificate issued by a CA such as Sectigo?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/using-signtool-to-verify-a-file-signature):

> The following command verifies a system file that may be signed in a catalog:
>
> SignTool verify /a SysFile.dll

1. Your DLL is not a system DLL, i.e. a DLL from Microsoft.
2. Your signature is part of your DLL, you don't have a Catalog file (`.cat`)

Timestamping is not related to this problem, IMHO.

But: use timestamping. Timestamping will enable that old versions of your DLL are still valid, if they were built and signed before the certificate breach. This can be important, e.g. if customers have old versions and can't or don't want to upgrade.

If your certificate was breached, then take some effort to identify the point in the past when it happened. And revoke the certificate for that point in the past. Don't just revoke the certificate "now".

If signtool is successful on your machine, but SQL server does not accept it, check if SQL server trusts the CA certificate (Sectigo, presumably) and import the CA certificate on SQL server, if needed.

Comment: The sql server in on my machine, and sectigo is a trusted CA by default